# Can detectBrowserLanguage be set to localstorage rather than cookies in nuxtjs/i18n

Tags: nuxt.js, internationalization

then, May I know why nuxtjs/i18n use cookies instead of localstorage?

And I want to know how to apply it in the language recognized by the app when I link it with the app.

I would like to know how to do it in localstorage instead of cookies in nuxtjs/i18n.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.